# Solving NP problems : analogy between the SAT problem and the shortest path problem

Tags: algorithms, graphs, computability, optimization, polynomial-time

in this 2minute-long video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TJ49N6WvT8M (pulled from a free udacity course on algorithms/theoretical computer sciences),

whose purpose is to show how a SAT problem can be solved as the shortest path problem would be,

I understand that

- there are `n` path paterns as `n` different boolean variables belonging to an "`AND` group of clauses". "Clause" being "an `OR` group" composed of conditions over some of the `n` variables.

   example : of a SAT problem being *"find values of `x1, x2, x3` such that `clause1 AND clause2 AND clause3` is true"*, with clause1 being `x1 OR x2` (is true), clause2 being `x1 OR NOT(x3)`, etc.
- `m` added vertices to force the `m` clauses to be ensured while having an unique "local" shortest path (within a local pattern)

But **the thing I don't understand** is why each pattern has to have `3(m+1)` vertices? Why 2 diamonds per pattern isn't sufficient ?

Thank you for enlighting me

Comment: It's really impossible to tell, since the rest of the video is missing. But according to the video, the number of diamonds should be at least the number of clauses using the variable. Since this is at most $m$, having $m$ diamonds will surely work.

Comment: Note that SAT is NP-hard while shortest path is in P. So you won't be able to reduce SAT to shortest path.